# php webservice basic authentication

Tags: php

i am creating web service using NUSOAP i want to add basic authentication to the webservice  so that client should send authentication header before he will be able to call webservice function so what will be my server side script  my client should send basic authentication server before calling to the hello function  I want to Secure my webservice functions

Answer (score 0):

To me, this depends on your webserver. For an apache server for example, see [this doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html)